# Printing 2D Arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays

Hello I have such a code and I would like to know why does it print only the first element of the array.

```
int main()
{
    double** mat;
    int n;
    int m; 
    printf("Input n,m\n");
    scanf("%d %d",&n,&m);

    mat = (double**)malloc(n*sizeof(double*));
    for( int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        mat[i] = (double*)malloc(m*sizeof(double));
        for( int j=0; j<m; j++)
        {
            mat[i][j]= i*i+j*j;
            printf("%lf\n",mat[i][j]);

            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

And I have one more question, what should I do if I want to print it in a matrix format?

Comment: Don't cast `malloc` in c.

Comment: Move the `return` statement to the end of `main` just before the `}` to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

You are returning the control out of `main` in the loop itself - change your code to:

```
int main()
{
    //... your code as it was before - fix your loops
    int sum = 0;
    for( int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        mat[i] = malloc(m*sizeof(double));
        for (int j = 0; j<m; j++)
        {
            mat[i][j] = i*i + j*j;
            printf("%lf ", mat[i][j]);
            sum = sum + mat[i][j];
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\nsum is %d.", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Input n,m 3 3
0.000000 1.000000 4.000000
1.000000 2.000000 5.000000
4.000000 5.000000 8.000000

sum is 30.
```

Comment: And I have one more question, what should I do if I want to print it in a matrix format?

Comment: @borbi - you need to place the `newline` in the outer loop - see my edits.

Comment: I have one more question. I would like to calculate the sum of all the elements of the matrix, it is as I remember double summation, and I try to do it like in a 1D array and it doesn't work:
int sum = 0;
sum =+ mat[i][j];
pfintf("\n %lf",sum);
Could you tell me where I'm wrong?